# Getting the last part of the referrer url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I wanted to get the last part of the referrer URL. How would be the best way to obtain this information?

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Currently this is how I am getting the referrer URL. This is giving me the entire URL, but I only want part of the URL.

**For Example:** Requested URL: `http://localhost:8080/TEST/ABC.html` 
If this is the referrer URL, I only want the `ABC.html`.

Thank you for the assistance, please let me know if there are any misunderstandings to my question.

Comment: Convert the String to a URL object and then use a getter method to parse out the portion you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you XYZ.html :

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/TEST/XYZ.html";
url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: @Austin Truong So why didn't you accept this answer?

Comment: Yeah I was going to accept, was waiting accept time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [java.net.URL.getFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29)

```
String path = new URL( request.getHeader( "referer" )).getPath();
int sep = path.lastIndexOf( '/' );
return ( sep < 0 ) ? path : path.substring( sep + 1 );
```

Comment: This returns TEST/ABC.html. Don't think that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

It's basic string manipulation, treat it like any other string. You can use `String.indexOf/String.lastIndexOf` and `String.substring`, or you can use `String.split`, or you can use `StringTokenizer`, or you can use Regular Expressions (the most flexible option, but requires learning regex).

Answer (score 0):

Just get the substring after the last `/` occurence.